# Find eigenvalue of $A$, where $A^2+2A=O$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Find eigenvalue of $A_{3\times3}$, where $A^2+2A=O$ , $r(A)=2$ and $A^{T}=A$.

$A\xi=\lambda\xi$, so I got ${\lambda}^2+2\lambda=0$, which means $\lambda_1=0$ and $\lambda_2=-2$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $r(A)=2$ means that $\lambda_3\ne 0$.

But the answer indicates that $\lambda_3=-2=\lambda_2$ without reasoning. Any hints or solutions would be helpful.

Comment: What is the order of $A$?

Comment: @Rise 3. I I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

An eigen value $\lambda$ satisfies $Ax = \lambda x$, where $x$ is a non-zero vector. Hence, if $x$ is an eigenvector, we have
$$A^2x + 2Ax = \lambda^2x + 2\lambda x = \lambda(\lambda+2)x = 0$$
which gives us $\lambda = 0,-2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are given a polynomial $P(A)$ such that $P(A)=0$, you know that the **only** possible eigenvalues of $A$ are roots of $P$.  Since your matrix is symmetric, it is diagonalizable, so this is an easy way to prove this to yourself.  Think about the case where $A$ is rank 2 and diagonal (diagonalization reduces it to this case) - your matrix looks like

$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc} \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right)
$$

If you compute $A^2+A$, you'll see that both $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ must satisfy $\lambda^2+\lambda = 0$, i.e. $\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda = -2$ are the only options.

The deeper theory here is related to the [minimal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_%28linear_algebra%29).

Comment: In other words, I have not enough information to get $\lambda_3$ in this case. So I CANT NOT  ACTUALLY get $\lambda_3$ without further information?

Comment: No, you know that $\lambda_3$ must be $-2$, as specified.  It's a double root - the characteristic polynomial will be $p(\lambda) = \lambda(\lambda+2)^2$, whereas $P(\lambda) = \lambda(\lambda+2)$ is the _minimal_ polynomial.

Comment: If $\lambda_3=-2$, then $r(A+2E)=1$. Right?

Comment: I think $r(A+2E)=1$ can not be induced from the given assumption.